# How do I get values from parameters?

Tags: c#, xml, parameters, fiddler

This may be a simple answer but I am having difficulty. I am using fiddler to see if various servers can connect to the internet. I am able to test it if the URL and proxy are hard coded as seen below

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
   request.Method = "GET";
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:9999");
   request.Proxy = myProxy;
```

I want to be able to test it using parms in an xml file. The parms look like this:

```
protected override void LoadParameters(IList<IRuleParameter> parms)
    {
        _url = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest;
        _proxy = new WebProxy();
    }
```

The parms are typed into the xml file like this:

```
<Parm name="Url" value="http://google.com" />
<Parm name="Proxy" value="http://localhost:9999" /
```

How can I call them so that I can place values into xml rather than placing values in the solution itself?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you reading the xml file? It seems like your code is pretty far from doing what you want or your example is incomplete. Why are you using `IRuleParameter`? If I was writing your code I would have a two line ini file and store those values in local variables. A second option is to use the app.config which already provides you with a dictionary of key-value config params but I unless your requirements are very different than what I'm expecting then I'd probably think that's more work than it's work.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create an Extension to fiddler. Have you read this http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Extend-Fiddler/ExtendWithDotNet ?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I tried using local variables but I got the following error: `cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.net.webproxy'` and `cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.net.httpwebrequest'` Using app.config also is not an option.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I actually got part of the code from fiddlers site. What I will be doing later is making an if statement. If the proxy is on, then have the code go through fiddler and test if connection is good and what not, otherwise go straight to the site.

Comment: @DesmondLost ok, I think I know what the problem is now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on your comment about why reading into local variables doesn't work. Can you double check the types of `_httpUrl` and `_httpProxy`? It sounds like those variables are of type `string` when they need to be `HttpWebRequest` and `WebProxy` respectively.

I think if you did;

```
   _httpUrl = paramVal;
```

it would compile and run with no problems. That error is saying `_httpUrl` is a `string` but you're trying to assign and `HttpWebRequest` to it. The other option for fixing it is changing the type of `_httpUrl`

```
    // definition where ever that is
    HttpWebRequest _httpUrl;


    //no code change required in body of LoadParams
    //this line caused the compiler error but will be fine now
    _httpUrl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(paramVal);
```

Remember to do give the same treatment to `_httpProxy`.

Comment: I had to rearrange some methods but that did the trick! Thanks